# What is the proper way to monitor payment to a monero address

Tags: monerod

I am trying to build a transactional system that:

1. Generates a new address for each customer.
2. Waits for the confirmed balance on the address to reach a certain value.
3. Launches a function once the balance condition is met.

I am currently using a while loop with polling to accomplish this, but it will not scale up properly for my intended use case.

Is there a way to register some kind of callback when a transaction is received to one of my wallet addresses and get rid of polling ?

Thank you all

Comment: Please clarify whether you are generating a full master wallet address for each customer, or whether you are just generating a subaddress (with each subaddress part of the same wallet) for each customer.

Comment: @knacc Subaddress for each customer. I am creating a new address with monero-python using wallet.new_address(). I believe it means this is a subaddress but I am still new at this. Would be awesome to be able to call a script when there is an incoming transaction to a local address.

Comment: I'm not familiar with monero-python, but unless you have code that talks to the daemon directly you are going to have to poll. You may find a method in https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html that allows you to see only the latest incoming transfers, rather than listing every single balance for every single subaddress.

Comment: @knaccc alright, I believe you are right and I have no other choice but to poll. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to poll if using the RPC interfaces to daemon / wallet.

> but it will not scale up properly for my intended use case

Nothing wrong with polling with regards to scaling. Just run the polling requests in a separate thread notifying your other code at appropriate times (e.g. when you detect new incoming transfers).